# SPI vs SCI on TI processor

Tags: c, embedded-systems, usb

I have a Texas Instruments development board: LAUNCHXL-F28027.

I'm confused on the difference between SPI (Serial Peripheral Interface) and SCI (Serial Communications Interface). What are their differences and where do they overlap as functionality? My goal is to make a bidirectional communication with the PC via USB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SCI is not a standard term.  Usually it's called a UART, and that's the interface you would use to communicate between the dev board and the PC.  SPI is used for communication between chips on a board, supports higher speeds, and has a single master clock.  UARTs are used for longer distances, each side asynchronously transmits their own data such that the clock can be recovered from it, and is usually transmitted at speeds just necessary for human interface devices such as keyboards.